# Traer datos de una consulta condicionada en SQL

Tags: sql

Estoy utilizando SQLServer, tengo la siguiente consulta en SQL

```sql
SELECT 
    sol.id as id,
    ciu.nombre as ciudad,
    bar.nombre as barrio
    FROM deportes_solicitudes sol
    -- Obtenemos la ciudad
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        dbo.deportes_ciudades as ciu
        LEFT JOIN deportes_usuarios usu_ciu ON ciu.id = usu_ciu.id
    ) ON sol.id_usuario = usu_ciu.id  
     -- Obtenemos el barrio
    LEFT OUTER JOIN (
        dbo.deportes_barrios as bar
        LEFT JOIN deportes_usuarios usu_bar ON bar.id = usu_bar.id
    ) ON sol.id_usuario = usu_bar.id
```

**Diagrama de la Base de datos**

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Quiero saber si es posible hacer lo siguiente con la consulta:

Si en la tabla `deportes_usuarios` tiene registrado un `id_barrio`, necesito que ademas de traerme el nombre del barrio me traiga el nombre de la ciudad (consultando el `id_ciudad` desde la tabla `deportes_barrios`).
Cuando se hace un registro, existe dos posibilidades que solamente especifique la ciudad, o que especifique un barrio, no existe posibilidad que en la tabla `deportes_usuarios` tenga `id_barrio` y `id_ciudad`.

Muchas gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Puedes resolverlo con una subconsulta en el SELECT

```html
SELECT 
    sol.id as id,
    bar.nombre as barrio,
    (select nombre_ciudad from deportes_ciudades c1 where c1.id = bar.id_ciudad) as ciudad
    FROM 
        deportes_solicitudes sol left join
        deportes_usuarios us ON sol.id_usuario = us.id left join
        deportes_barrios bar ON us.id_barrio = bar.id left join
```

Comment: Configure bien la consulta para que se adapte, porque me arrojaba un error.
Igual no esta trayendo la ciudad con esa subquerry

Comment: Te refieres a la coma después de bar.nombre as barrio? Ya está entonces.

Comment: Si, eso lo arregle, pero después es como mencione, no me trae la ciudad, ademas no puedo usar los JOIN que usaste, no me funcionan lo que hice fue agregar a mi consulta original
(select nombre_ciudad from deportes_ciudades c1 where c1.id = bar.id_ciudad) as ciudad

Comment: Haciendo la subconsulta en el SELECT, no hace falta que en los JOINS añadas la tabla deportes_ciudades.

Comment: Si, en ese caso no la estoy utilizando. Pero como te digo, la columna ciudad no trae nada

Comment: Sería posible que no traiga nada, porque el id de la ciudad no esté definida en la tabla deporte_ciudades

Comment: Si. Tengo definido 7 ciudades, IDs del 1 al 7.

Comment: Y el id_barrio de la tabla deportes_usuarios está definido en deportes_barrios?

Comment: Si, perdon ahi lo pude solucionar, tenia una inconsistencia en la base de datos, error mio. Ahora me trae el barrio y la ciudad a que esta ese barrio. Pero el usuario si solo tiene id_ciudad y no id_barrio no me muestra la ciudad

Comment: Entonces en la consulta, puedes realizar un left join desde deportes_usuarios tanto con deportes_ciudades como deportes_barrios, sino está definidos obtendrás NULL pero si están definidos obtendrás resultado.

Comment: Eso lo hago en la consulta general o en la subconsulta?

Comment: En la general, si haces esto y obtienes los datos de las 4 tablas no necesitas la subconsulta.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la ayuda, tengo que practicar mas con SQL, es así de simple como lo mencionas.

Comment: Ahora me trae la ciudad si tiene o el barrio si tiene. Pero ahora como hago si yo tengo el barrio que me traiga el barrio y la ciudad relacionada con el barrio?

Comment: Yo creo que deberías mejorar las estructura de las tablas, para mi, podrías hacer en la tabla deportes_usuarios solo tener el id_ciudad, después creas una tabla barrios donde relacionas de una ciudad muchos barrios, una relación 1 a n.

Comment: Lo que sucede que yo tengo que informar a que barrio pertenece cada usuario. Y ademas hay ciudades que no tienen barrios, para el dominio que estoy manejando. Estuve viendo y puede ser que con SQL CASE se puede solucionar

Comment: Claro, habrá ciudades que no tendrán barrios, no pasa nada, puedes solucionarlo con la subconsulta de la que hablamos.

Comment: Ahi lo pude solucionar de otra forma usando CASE. Muchas gracias por toda la ayuda!!